# Timer + Aframe : How to use setTimeOut for Aframe.registercomponent("...")

Tags: html, time, components, settimeout, aframe

I know it's a beginner's question but I have a bit of trouble with html / javascript.
I learned about the setTimeout (function, time) and I knew how to use it by creating a function.
However, I was wondering if it is possible to use this setTimeOut for Aframe.registercomponent my other scripts? I didn't find anything on that and all my attempts failed.

**For example for the "audioanalyser-waveform":**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('audioanalyser-waveform', {
  dependencies: ['audioanalyser'],

  schema: {
    maxHeight: {default: 0.2},
    multiplier: {default: .01},
    radius: {default: 1},
  },

  init: function () {
    this.colors = [];
    this.geometry;
    this.levels = [];
    this.noisePos = 0;
    this.rings = [];
  },


  update: function () {
    setTimeout(Color, 4000);
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;
    var i; 
    ...
    ...
```

This one is in my wave.js script
and i know i can call it in my index.html with the tags:

```
      <a-entity id="analyser"
        audioanalyser="src: #song"
        audioanalyser-waveform="radius: 1"
        rotation="210 0 0"
        position="0 100 -150"
      ></a-entity>
```

And it would have been so simple if I could add that :

```
 <script> setTimeout(audioanalyser-waveform, 4000); </script>
```

But it doesn't work like that and I don't have idea how to set the start / stop of an Aframe.registercomponent to choose its seconds of play.

Can you help me please...

Pulsar,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish? Can you have a component that sets `audioanalyser-waveform` after 4000ms?

```
  <a-entity id="analyser"
    audioanalyser="src: #song"
    rotation="210 0 0"
    position="0 100 -150"
    your-component
  ></a-entity>
```

Component code:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('your-component', {
  ...
  init: function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.setAttribute('audioanalyser-waveform', {radius: 1});
    }, 4000)
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: I try to create an ""animation music video" and my video must match the music.

Yes, it is working ! Thank you !! Mmmh... is it possible to stop my component after 8000ms for example ?

(Thanks)

Comment: Using `setTimeout` is probably not the best way to sync with music but you can do `this.el.removeAttribute('audioanalyser-waveform')` or define methods `start / stop` in your component that you can call: `this.el.components['audioanalyser-waveform'].start()`

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer yesterday.
I have some difficult to write these methods start/stop, it is why I prefer setTimeout haha :^)
Thank you so much for your help, it is working ! Good evening Diego !